# Why can't NSE be used with functions stored in lists in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I recently found it useful to store functions in lists for data analysis. However, I noticed that normal functions and functions stored in lists behave differently. I am not familiar with all of them, but it seems that functions stored in lists are not specifically allowed to use the NSE notation. An example is shown below.

Why can't NSE be used with functions stored in lists?
Also, what is the overall difference between normal functions and functions stored in lists?

```r
# function stored in list
x <- tibble::lst(
  f = \(var) {
    var <- rlang::enquo(var)
    mtcars |> 
      dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(!!var))
  }
)

x$f(var = mpg)
#> Warning in mean.default(function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use) : argument is
#> not numeric or logical: returning NA
#>   mean
#> 1   NA

# normal function
f <- \(var) {
  var <- rlang::enquo(var)
  mtcars |> 
    dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(!!var))
}

f(var = mpg)
#>       mean
#> 1 20.09062
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Edit**:
As zephryl pointed out, it looks like the problem was caused by using `tibble::lst()`. I still don't know why it doesn't work with `lst()`, but it looks like I should just use `list()` for now.

---

**Edit2**:
G. Grothendieck pointed out that an NSE implementation using `eval()` and `substitute()` would work fine with `lst()`. So, the initial problem seems to be a complex one involving the use of `lst()` and the NSE implementation with {rlang}.

I do not know more than this with my little knowledge, but new answers are always welcome.

```r
x <- tibble::lst(
  f = \(var) eval(substitute({
    mtcars |> dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(var))
    }))
  )
x$f(var = mpg)
#>       mean
#> 1 20.09062
```

In addition, a very interesting technique was demonstrated.

```r
x <- tibble::lst(
  f = !!\(var) {
    var <- rlang::enquo(var)
    mtcars |>
      dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(!!var))
  }
)
x$f(var = mpg)
#>       mean
#> 1 20.09062
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the fact that `tibble::lst()` quotes arguments using `quos()`. I’m not sure *why* this messes up the function exactly, beyond the vague idea that multiple layers of quosures makes things wonky. At any rate, your code runs fine if you use `list()` rather than `tibble::lst()`.

Comment: @zephryl Oh I see. I should have tried `list()` before asking the question! It certainly seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: It does work with `lst` if base R is used to implement the NSE instead of rlang.  `x <- tibble::lst(
  f = \(var) eval(substitute({
      mtcars |> dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(var))
  }))
)`

Comment: I see, the rlang spec has something to do with it. Maybe it is not supposed to store functions in a list in rlang. I will consider implementation using `eval()` and `substitute()`. Thanks!

Comment: The code in the question works if we replace `f = \(var)` with `f = !!\(var)` .

Comment: I just checked `f = !!\(var)`. What is the principle behind this? I'm a bit puzzled because this is the first time I've seen a bang-bang operator prefixed to a function, but it sure works fine. Amazing!